# How can I add a functional Java key listener to a panel under the card layout?

Tags: java, focus, panel, keylistener, windowbuilder

I was designing a program which has multiple layers(panels), and I want these panels to be keyboard sensitive so that I can press ESC to exit to the main menu (First panel) at any time.

Here is the switch panel code that I've written:

```
public void switchPane(JPanel jp) {
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().removeAll();
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().add(jp);
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().repaint();
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().revalidate();
        jp.requestFocusInWindow();

}
```

I know that in order for the panel to be keyboard sensitive, it needs to be focusable.

Here's the code I have written for the initialisation of one of the panels:

```
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setFocusable(true);
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().add(panel2, "name_83147693736131");
        panel2.setLayout(null);

        panel2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("panel2: " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                    switchPane(panel1);
                }
            }
        });
        JButton btnReturnToMain = new JButton("Return to main page");
        btnReturnToMain.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switchPane(panel1);
            }
        });
        btnReturnToMain.setBounds(279, 431, 236, 50);
        panel2.add(btnReturnToMain);
```

I have deleted most of the unrelated functions and codes.

What I wish to accomplish is that when the switch page button is clicked, the switchPane method is executed, and the new panel automatically gets the focus with the requestFocusInWindow(); command, so that user can type ESC to return to the main menu.

When I tried to run the program, it turns out that for the first time I entered a sub-panel, it can not get the focus and does not respond to the keyboard. However, if I return to the main panel using the return button and re-enter the same sub-panel, this time it automatically gets the focus and is responding to the keyboard.

I have no idea why the program shows such behaviour. The following is the full program. Please notice that in the full program I also added a click to get focus function which works. However, I wish the newly opened panel can automatically get the focus and responding to the keys without the user actually clicking the panel.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class mainFrame {

    private JFrame frmDavidsAppstore;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JPanel panel3;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mainFrame window = new mainFrame();
                    window.frmDavidsAppstore.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public mainFrame() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void switchPane(JPanel jp) {
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().removeAll();
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().add(jp);
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().repaint();
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().revalidate();
        jp.requestFocusInWindow();
        System.out.println(KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner());
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmDavidsAppstore = new JFrame();
        frmDavidsAppstore.setResizable(false);
        frmDavidsAppstore.setTitle("David's appstore");
        frmDavidsAppstore.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frmDavidsAppstore.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setFocusable(true);
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().add(panel1, "name_83127645466169");
        panel1.setLayout(null);

        panel1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("panel1: " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
            }
        });

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Open page 2");
        button2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switchPane(panel2);
            }
        });
        button2.setBounds(279, 344, 236, 50);
        panel1.add(button2);

        JButton button3 = new JButton("Open page 3");
        button3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switchPane(panel3);
            }
        });
        button3.setBounds(279, 432, 236, 50);
        panel1.add(button3);

        JLabel background = new JLabel("");
        background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(mainFrame.class.getResource("/images/background_main.jpg")));
        background.setBounds(0, 0, 794, 565);
        panel1.add(background);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                panel2.requestFocusInWindow();
                System.out.println(KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner());
            }
        });
        panel2.setFocusable(true);
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().add(panel2, "name_83147693736131");
        panel2.setLayout(null);

        panel2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("panel2: " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                    switchPane(panel1);
                }
            }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane_1.setBounds(130, 104, 533, 270);
        panel2.add(scrollPane_1);

        JTextArea txtrIAmPage = new JTextArea();
        txtrIAmPage.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(txtrIAmPage);
        txtrIAmPage.setText("I am page2");

        JButton btnReturnToMain = new JButton("Return to main page");
        btnReturnToMain.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switchPane(panel1);
            }
        });
        btnReturnToMain.setBounds(279, 431, 236, 50);
        panel2.add(btnReturnToMain);

        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                panel3.requestFocusInWindow();
                System.out.println(KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner());
            }
        });
        panel3.setFocusable(true);
        frmDavidsAppstore.getContentPane().add(panel3, "name_83334788966651");
        panel3.setLayout(null);

        panel3.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("panel3: " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                    switchPane(panel1);
                }
            }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(130, 104, 533, 270);
        panel3.add(scrollPane);

        JTextArea txtrIAmPage_1 = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(txtrIAmPage_1);
        txtrIAmPage_1.setText("I am page3");

        JButton button = new JButton("Return to main page");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switchPane(panel1);
            }
        });
        button.setBounds(279, 431, 236, 50);
        panel3.add(button);
    }
}
```

I have been working on it for a day now and couldn't figure out why. Thank you guys so much for any help or advices.

Apreciated!

Problem solved!!! You need to add .setVisible(true); before .requestFocusInWindow(); in order for it to work!

Comment: I'd use the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) - it overcomes the short comings of `KeyListener` and doesn't require fragile hacks

Comment: Problem solved!!! You need to add .setVisible(true); before .requestFocusInWindow(); in order for it to work!

Comment: That is a hack which will fail the moment another component gets focus, better to use the key bindings api and solve the core problem